# Python Django saved posts computed method

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, model

Assuming im using the default django model, a Post model (code below) and a SavedPost model that links a User to a Post (if the certain user with the certain post exists then that post is saved for that user) and a Follower model that links 2 user (similar to SavedPost).

What im trying to do: An API that for a user, they get all posts for the users they follow, in addition each of these posts has an extra 'field' to say if that post is saved or not.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('B', 'Blog'), ('V', 'Video')], default='B')
    file_path = models.URLField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class SavedPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        # A user can save a post only once.
        unique_together = ('user', 'post')

class Follower(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        # A user can follow another user only once
        unique_together = ('user', 'follower')
```

Post serilializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Nested serializer for post using SimpleUser and Kingdom.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'post_type', 'file_path',
                  'title', 'description', 'created_at', 'updated_at')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['user'] = UserSerializer(
            User.objects.get(pk=data['user'])).data
        return data
```

API View:

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated,])
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_following(request):
    user = request.user
    following = Follower.objects.filter(follower=user).values('user')
    # saved_posts = SavedPost.objects.filter(user=user, post__user__in=following).order_by('-post__created_at')
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=following).order_by('-created_at')

    serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

So far with the view I made I can get all the posts that the request.user follows but it doesnt say if they are saved or not. I am looking for say 'is_saved' boolean on post to say if that post is saved for that user or not.

Any help/method to do this appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you add the `PostSerializer` serializer?

Comment: Added PostSerializer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`serializers.SerializerMethodField`** as

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_saved = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_is_saved(self, post_instance):
        return SavedPost.objects.filter(user=post_instance.user, post=post_instance).exists()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'post_type', 'file_path',
                  'title', 'description', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'is_saved']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['user'] = UserSerializer(
            User.objects.get(pk=data['user'])).data
        return data
```

Comment: This worked, one thing missing 'is_saved' should be added to fields. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just to be clear, I will be defining the `related_name` option for the `ForeignKey`s in `SavedPost` - it's up to you to decide whether to implement this or not:

```
class SavedPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="saved", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="saved", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Now, in your `PostSerializer`, you could add this field (remember to add it to the `fields` variable in the `Meta` inner class - that is if you're using `ModelSerializer`):

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    saved = SavedPostSerializer(many=True)
    ...
```

To finish it off, define your `SavedPostSerializer` - above `PostSerializer`, if in the same file/module:

```
class SavedPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SavedPost
        fields = "__all__"
```

With this, your json should have a nested field with the `saved` key containing an array of `SavedPost`s, if there are any related to the `Post`s retrieved.

Comment: I see what you mean. Is there a way to make the 'saved' attribute from PostSerializer a boolean? To be true if there is a saved post and false if not.

Comment: In this case, maybe you could override `to_representation` in `PostSerializer` and assign its value based on if there are any elements in the `saved` list; e.g. `bool(data["saved"])`.